# How can I set a checkbox custom field via API

Tags: checkbox, docusignapi

I am setting custom fields in a template via the DocuSign API from Salesforce.  This works great for text fields.  I am having trouble setting a checkbox field to checked.  What is the value to send to a checkbox field so it shows as checked?

Here is an example of code to set text fields:

```
DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceFieldDataDataValue fd0 = new DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceFieldDataDataValue();    
fd0.TabLabel = 'Lead Name';    
fd0.Value = c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName;
```

I've tried setting the Value to `true`, `checked`, `Checked`, `TRUE` but  none of these seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the official documentation of the [CheckBox Tab](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Checkbox%20Tab.htm), in order to your check box checked, you need to set the following property to true as my example in C# below :

```
Checkbox myCheckBox = new Checkbox
            {
                Selected = "true"
            };
```